# PHP str_replace Array Key pair

Tags: php, arrays, replace

This may be a newbie question, but I am not getting it .

I have an array say :

```
$form = Array
(
    [Resource_ID] => 5251
)
```

and I want the output as

```
 $form = Array
    (
        [Resource ID] => 5251
    )
```

Underscore should be replaced by a space.

I tried

```
foreach($form as $key => $value)
{
 $form [$key] = str_replace("_"," ",$form [$key]);
}
```

But this is not working !
Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Try adding quotes in array if you are not using underscore `array(["resource id"] => 5251)`

Comment: You can't change an array key *inplace*, you'll have to add a new one and remove the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use such code

```
foreach($form as $key => $value)
{
  $abc[str_replace("_"," ",$key)] = $value;
  // unset($abc[$key]); <- this could cause problem
}
```

or even

```
foreach($form as $key => $value)
{
  $pos = strpos($key,'_');
  if ($pos !== false) {
     $abc[str_replace("_"," ",$key)] = $value;
     unset($abc[$key]);
  }
}
```

But in both cases you should consider what to do if you have keys: `key 1` and `key_1`. It seems that you can override value or even remove it (depending if you will use unset or not).